# js remove character untill $

Tags: javascript

i have a php select dropdown with BBQ|$5 and a JS function that increase the price in $5.. a need a function in JS to get just the 5 and add to the price... i have this but i can make it work...(catxs1 its the id of the `<option>`

```
var ext_st = document.getElementById("catxs1");
var ext_val = parseInt(document.getElementById("catxs1").value);
ext_st = str.substring(ext_st.indexOf("$"));
```

so ... i say.. ext_st MUST be just the 5... but have no response... what can be wrong in my code??

Comment: _"i have a php select dropdow"_ - PHP doesn't have any "select dropdown". The posted code is all JS and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: `ext_st` is the element, you can't get the index of it. `document.getElementById("catxs1").value ` is probably the value you're looking for, but you've completely botched it by running it through parseInt. Try running your code here in the browser's developer console on that page, and you'll see exactly what you're getting and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following to get everything after the $:

```
let ext_val = document.getElementById("catxs1").value; // this I think should return the string: "BBQ|$5";

let ext_st = ext_val.substring(ext_val.indexOf('$') + 1);

console.log(ext_st);
```